# Android: Get notification when user enters specific location

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an android application that will give a notification when the user enters into an area on a road marked between two points.  I know how to create a route between two points but is there a simpler way as I do not need to give the user directions, I just need to notify them when they enter that area of road. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android, check gps position if near/close to certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099589/android-check-gps-position-if-near-close-to-certain-position)

Comment: These deal with perimeter and a radius, I am looking for something that marks the road in between these points and notifies users when they are on that road, I don't want a radius.

Comment: You should check out Geofire by FireBase Google